# How to create an XML file in PHP then send it as attachment via email

Tags: php

I could do this, but I'm not sure if I have to create the file on my server then attach it, or can I just create a temp file that doesn't reside on my server and still send it as an attachment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the open source Swift Mailer library, http://swiftmailer.org/, you can create a temp file that doesn't reside on your server using the following code:

```
<?php
require_once "lib/Swift.php";
require_once "lib/Swift/Connection/NativeMail.php";
$swift =& new Swift(new Swift_Connection_NativeMail());
$message =& new Swift_Message("My subject");
$message->attach(new Swift_Message_Part("I have attached a file to this message!"));
$message->attach(new Swift_Message_Attachment(
  '<xml>Whateveryouwant</xml>', "file.xml", "application/xml"));
$swift->send($message, "my-friend@host.tld", "me@my-domain.tld");
```

(Sample code taken from http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/tutorials/attachments)